# Wait for promise to resolve in not related to it callback

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, callback, event-handling

I am developing a Steam bot (but the question is only about JS). I have the following code:

```js
const steam = new SteamUser(); // from steam-user library

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function steamAddFriend(user_steam_id) {
    // 3 attempts
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
            await steam.addFriend(user_steam_id);
            console.log('Friend request is sent');
            // everything is ok
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.eresult === SteamUser.EResult.DuplicateName) {
                if (steam.myFriends[user_steam_id] === SteamUser.EFriendRelationship.Friend) {
                    console.log('This user is already in the friends list');
                } else if (steam.myFriends[user_steam_id] === SteamUser.EFriendRelationship.RequestInitiator) {
                    console.log('The friend request has already been sent earlier');
                }
                // non-critical error, but there is no point to continue trying
            } else if ((err.eresult === SteamUser.EResult.ServiceUnavailable || err.message === 'Request timed out') && i < 2) {
                // problem with Steam servers, wait 10 seconds and try again
                await sleep(10000);
                continue;
            } else {
                // critical error. for example, user_steam_id is invalid
                // sendNotification is fetch based function to send notification to me
                await sendNotification();
            }
        }
        break; // break the loop if there is no need to continue trying
    }
    try {
        // fetch based function to send updates to backend
        await sendUpdate1(user_steam_id);
    } catch (err) {
        // handle error
    }
}

// fired when relationship with user is changed (for example, a user accepted a friend request)
steam.on('friendRelationship', async (sid, relationship) => {
    if (relationship === SteamUser.EFriendRelationship.Friend) {
        const user_steam_id = sid.getSteamID64();
        console.log('User is added to friends');
        // here I need to wait until sendUpdate1 resolves
        // sendUpdate2 is fetch based function to send updates to backend
        await sendUpdate2(user_steam_id);
    }
});

steamAddFriend('71111111111111111');
```

I need `friendRelationship` callback to wait for the `sendUpdate1` promise to resolve before calling `sendUpdate2`. How can I do this? Keep in mind that the bot can work with several users at the same time.

Comment: Is this code complete? your steamAddFriend function for instance does not even have the async keyword before the function definition. This should result in a SyntaxError

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I'm sorry, the code has been simplified for the question. There is an async keyword in the original code.

Comment: Also, (and yes it is nitpicking) I would pass the `steam` instance together with the `user_steam_id` to `steamAddFriend`, if only for the sake of making the audience less think about the code. Something like ... `steamAddFriend(steam, '71111111111111111')`.

Comment: @Nitor ... At which point does `'friendRelationship'` get triggered?

Comment: @PeterSeliger `steam` is a global variable. I edited the question.

Comment: @PeterSeliger `friendRelationship` is triggered when Steam servers send a specific packet over a TCP connection and steam-user library processes it.

Comment: @Nitor ... Does it happen, before `steamAddFriend` is settled (resolved, rejected) or while it is still in pending state? In case the `'friendRelationship'` related event handling is part of the `steamAddFriend` process, what are the arguments against making the latter function's last `try-catch` block ... `try { await sendUpdate1(user_steam_id); } catch (err) { ... }` .. part of the handler function, where awaiting `sendUpdate1` seems to be more logical since awaiting `sendUpdate2` happens there as well?

Comment: @PeterSeliger Usually `friendRelationship` is triggered after `steamAddFriend` is settled. But sometimes `sendUpdate1` takes longer (this is an http request) and the order of actions (first `sendUpdate1`, then `sendUpdate2`) is broken. I can't add `friendRelationship` handler to the end of `steamAddFriend` because `friendRelationship` is triggered when the user has accepted a friend request (and he may not accept it or accept it after a long time). Adding a handler for each user can potentially lead to a memory leak.

Comment: "*the order of actions (first `sendUpdate1`, then `sendUpdate2`) is broken.*" - really the proper solution is to drop this requirement. Make your backend accept the requests in any order. If there really is a hard requirement for some reason, check it and enforce it in your backend, not in the client code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to store the promise returned by `steamAddFriend` in a lookup map keyed by user id:

```
const openFriendRequests = new Map();

steam.on('friendRelationship', async (sid, relationship) => {
    if (relationship === SteamUser.EFriendRelationship.Friend) {
        const userSteamId = sid.getSteamID64();
        console.log(`User is added to friends of ${userSteamId}`);
        const request = openFriendRequests.get(userSteamId);
        if (request) {
            openFriendRequests.delete(userSteamId);
            await request; // wait until sendUpdate1 resolves
            await sendUpdate2(userSteamId);
        } else {
            console.log('not a response to a friend request created by this code');
        }
    }
});

openFriendRequest.set('71111111111111111', steamAddFriend('71111111111111111'));
```

Comment: Good idea, but the user may not accept the friend request or accept it after a long time. Storing promises can potentially lead to a memory leak.

Comment: The memory might grow if there are a lot of open friend requests, but it should not *leak*, if all the requests are eventually accepted. How many users are we talking about here? I just had implicitly assumed that you were running this code for multiple different user ids. What else can happen to the requests, do you also get an event when they get declined?

Comment: Alternatively, you can store a mapping of friend requests with an active update1 request, i.e. `activeFriendRequests.set(id, steamAddFriend(id).finally(() => { activeFriendRequests.delete(id); }))`. Then in the `on('friendRelationship')` handler you wait for the `request` promise only if it still exists, and always call `sendUpdate2`.

Comment: Either way, you'll have to decide what you want to do with `friendRelationship` events that were not caused by actions of your program. Do you still want to `sendUpdate2` anyway? Do you want to ignore them? Do you need to distinguish between multiple separate runs of your program (or: how do you deal with restarts of your server)? If these things are important, you'll need a persistence layer of some sort.

Comment: Yes, `friendRelationship` is triggered when user declines the request. But it is not guaranteed that all the requests will be eventually accepted, I deal with real users after all. I use a cheap VPS with a small amount of RAM and don't want to waste it on storing pending requests. Everything is stored in the DB and `friendRelationship` events are verified by the backend. Your alternative suggestion seems to fit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are awaiting in the event handler of `friendRelationship`. If it's not a requirement to await, this is how I would write it:

```js
// fired when relationship with user is changed (for example, a user accepted a friend request)
steam.on('friendRelationship', (sid, relationship) => {
    if (relationship === SteamUser.EFriendRelationship.Friend) {
        const user_steam_id = sid.getSteamID64();
        console.log('User is added to friends');
        sendUpdate1(user_steam_id).then(() => sendUpdate2(user_steam_id));
    }
});
```

The handler of `steam.on` finishes immediately, but the `sendUpdate1` will execute async, and once it's done, execute `sendUpdate2`, also async.

Comment: `sendUpdate1` needs to be called immediately after friend request is sent (i.e. `steam.addFriend` is resolved). `friendRelationship` is triggered when friend request is accepted (`sendUpdate2` should be called only after that).